# Array Initialiser Too Large In ajax Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I made ajax request for getting byte of data from server using jquery.but when I  get response from server at that time I get following error. 
**array initialiser too large**
So is there any way to find out solution.
I have following code.

```
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test',
            contentType: 'application/jsonp',
            crossdomain: true,
            dataType: "text",           
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (txt) {                   
            }
        });
```

Comment: any code to get us starting?

Comment: A quick search shows issues like https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686274 - you might have to chunk your array into smaller pieces and combine them on the client side.

Comment: Can you tell me what is response limit for ajax response.

Comment: See comment 3 on given link above or [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=686274#c3)

Comment: It's browser specific. Just because Firefox breaks at 450k doesn't mean it's guaranteed other browsers will support 400k. Just pick a number, a nice round number. For bonus points, see if you can try/catch the error and handle it somehow.